# append facebook comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I can call for facebook comments like this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.google.com/" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Now I want to call it dynamically with 'append' to a div called '.description' like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('.embed').find('.description').append('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.google.com/" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>');
}, 1000);
```

The problem is that it doesnt append. take a look at the example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLMZk/2/)

I also have put the facebook comments as regular div inside the HTML part just to show there is nothing wrong with the facebook script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to implement the Facebook [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). This SDK has a function called `FB.XFBML.parse()`.

> This function parses and renders XFBML markup in a document on the
>   fly. This could be used if you send XFBML from your server via ajax
>   and want to render it client side. XFBML enables you to incorporate
>   FBML into your websites and IFrame applications.

All you'd have to do is append the comment plugin code and then execute the `FB.XFBML.parse()` function on the ID of the containing element.

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('facebook_comments_holder'));
```

With jQuery (and in your specific example), I believe the code you would need is this -

```
// assuming the folowing selector matches only one element
var element = $('.embed').find('.description')[0];
FB.XFBML.parse(element);
```

Comment: I think anwser is good (but Im having trouble implementing http://jsfiddle.net/rLMZk/11/) Thank you

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that code will work in jsFiddle... As you can see there are many JavaScript errors and warnings. Are you getting any errors in your code (not in jsFiddle)?

Comment: @you - as I suspected, it was an issue with loading those javascript extensions into jsFiddle. Here is a working example of that fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rLMZk/15/. You can see in the left sidebar there is a  "manage resources" area. I've placed the Facebook and other plugins there. Take a look :)

Comment: Thanks you very much:) I actually did consider the problem on jsfiddle side but I had to wait to get home in order to test it from my server.